# Mock ProtectedSessionStorage getting always same value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, blazor, bunit

I'm building some unit tests for Blazor using bUnit.

At the moment I'm trying to mock correctly ProtectedSessionStorage because of the usage of SessionStorage in my components.

This is the implementation of the Mock that I have right now:

```
public class MockDataProtectionProvider
    {
        public Mock<IDataProtectionProvider> Mock = new Mock<IDataProtectionProvider>();
        private Mock<IDataProtector>? mockDataProtector;

        #region Private Methods
        #endregion

        public void SetAll(BunitJSInterop JSInterop)
        {
            SetCountry(JSInterop);
            SetLanguage(JSInterop);
        }

        public void SetLanguage(BunitJSInterop JSInterop)
        {
            Set("1", "_language", JSInterop);
        }

        public void SetCountry(BunitJSInterop JSInterop)
        {
            Set("55BBF40F-3693-478E-948A-FB2321DB7771", "_countryId", JSInterop);
        }

        private void Set(string value, string key, BunitJSInterop JSInterop)
        {
            mockDataProtector = new Mock<IDataProtector>();
            // This string will be the json of the object you want
            // to receive when GetAsync is called from your ProtectedSessionStorage.
            string valueJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);

            // Encode the valueJson directly as a byte array.
            byte[] valueBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valueJson);

            // Base64 used internally on the ProtectedSessionStorage.
            byte[] protectedValueBytes = mockDataProtector.Object.Protect(valueBytes);
            string base64valueJson = Convert.ToBase64String(protectedValueBytes);

            // Notice how the mocked methods return the json.
            mockDataProtector.Setup(sut => sut.Protect(It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Returns(protectedValueBytes);
            mockDataProtector.Setup(sut => sut.Unprotect(It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Returns(valueBytes);
            Mock.Setup(s => s.CreateProtector(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockDataProtector.Object);
            JSInterop.Setup<String>("sessionStorage.getItem", key).SetResult(base64valueJson);
        }
    }
```

This is the way that is being called to inject it:

```
      //Prepare JSInterop to get set data into SessionStorage
      DataProtectionProviderMock.SetAll(JSInterop);
      _protectedSessionStorage = new ProtectedSessionStorage(
           JSInterop.JSRuntime, DataProtectionProviderMock.Mock.Object);
      Services.AddSingleton(_protectedSessionStorage);
```

This is when I get the values injected in the component that I'm currently testing:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var languageIdResult = await Storage.GetAsync<int>(nameof(_language));
            var countryIdResult = await Storage.GetAsync<Guid>(nameof(_countryId));

            _language = languageIdResult.Success ? languageIdResult.Value : default;
            _countryId = countryIdResult.Success ? countryIdResult.Value : default;

        }
    }
```

My real problem in this implementation is that I'm getting always the same value even if I use the different keys, for example:

- When getting the value for "_language" key, I'm getting correctly the value 1
- When getting the value for "_countryId" key, I'm getting the value 1 that corresponds to the "_language" key

I tried different types of implementations but this is the only one that retrieves at least one of the values and in this one if I change the "Set" to set first the language instead of the country, I only get the value for the "_countryId" key, so I just assume that is overriding in some way.

The goal is to have both values correctly for each key.

Can you help me find the problem in this implementation?

Edit: forgot to mention that my .cs for the UnitTest has as base class the "TestContext" from bUnit so I can use JSInterop implemented on it

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is almost a year old, I had a very similar issue last week and decided to answer this in case it helps anyone.

It has to do with how you are using Mock. `It.IsAny<byte[]>()` will return the mock response for any input. If you want to return a specific response for a specific input, you need to do something like `It.Is<byte[]>(input => input.SequenceEqual(valueBytes))`

Additional Notes:

- I'm not sure if doing `new Mock<IDataProtector>();` every single time will overwrite the previous Mock.
- If you are mocking a datatype that is not a string, converting it to a string before serializing the json may error out on executing your tests
- For example: I tried to mock a bool value from session storage just like your pasted code. `JsonSerializer.Serialize(true);` ultimately returned a bool value from session storage, vs `JsonSerializer.Serialize("true");` returned a string "true" from session storage that, for some reason, couldn't be parsed into a bool -- strings might still be able to cast into guids properly though